# How to set HTTPS proxy in Privoxy?

Tags: proxy, https, privoxy

How can I set an HTTPS proxy with authentication in Privoxy
to use in Proxifier?

[image]

Comment: See https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html#ENABLE-PROXY-AUTHENTICATION-FORWARDING